# Will installing ruby slow down my vps?

Tags: php, ruby

I have a vps that's running mostly php sites.

I want to install ruby. Will installing ruby but not doing much with it take away resources from the php sites?

Thanks

Comment: Will depend a bit on how you're going to serve the pages (IIRC, Ruby needs a Web server to serve content?) If you can handle both languages with the same Apache instance, there should be not much additional resource use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I assume you're talking about `mod_ruby` or similar - in this case there will be a few megabytes or so added to the Apache (or otherwise) process, but unless you're actively using it it'll stay out of the way. If you're running Ruby as CGI scripts, Ruby won't even be in play until somebody requests a `.rb` file in a CGI configured directory.

But you don't need to take our word for it. You can always try it yourself and see if it causes any problems. I don't expect so, though.